# T568 wires swapped Pin #3 and #6?

Tags: networking, home-networking

Whilst putting on Keystones on our home which is pre-wired with Cat-7 cables I am a bit confused. From what I can tell from looking at how the wall plugs are connected it looks like all wires are connected following the T568-A mapping ... except for Pin #3 which has orange solid (instead of the expected white/orange) and Pin #6 which looks like it has white/orange (where the reverse was expected.

Question now is if this matters?  I have so far only checked one wall connection wiring.

UPDATE: I just checked a couple more wall connections and it seems 3 and 6 are swapped everywhere. As user1686 mentioned in the comments, it won't cause any problems but it does annoy me a bit that the installer decided to swap them everywhere. Maybe it was his signature, his scheme?

[image: Suspected Swapped T568-A Wires]

Comment: Also, I'm not up to date with the modern standards but this "Cat 6" jack looks suspicious (or just heavily worn). The pins seem a bit misaligned, and is there _paint_ between pins 1 and 2?

Comment: The cable is a Cat 7 but plugs are Cat 6A. I'll have a closer look and may need to check a few other wall plugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the swapped wires **belong to the same pair** – 3 and 6 are paired – it shouldn't really cause any problems for the connection, though it will cause confusion every time someone looks at those jacks in the future.

(And, of course, both ends of the same cable must be wired identically. So either fix that properly here, or make sure they're swapped on the other end too.)

On the other hand, if you had different twisted pairs mixed up (e.g. half green and half orange), that would definitely cause problems for the signal integrity.

Comment: That was my thought too but I was not sure. It's a new-ish home in Germany and so far I only checked one wall jack. I'd rather indeed fix it up and have wiring matching a standard to avoid confusion.